# How to clear input text field value inside a block

Tags: visualforce-component, inputtext

I am displaying 6 text field using apex repeat. Now i am placing a command link called " Clear Filter" to reset the value to null. I am not able to get the id of the inputtext since it is inside a section. Here is my code

```
function clearFilter () {
        alert('Inside');
        var a = document.getElementById("{!$Component.searchTextId}").value
        alert('Hiii');
    }
<apex:form id="frm">

    <div class="centered">
        <apex:actionStatus id="LoadingStatus">
        <apex:facet name="start">

        <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ProgressIndicator)}" />
        </apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="stop">
        </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>        
    </div>

    <div class="centered">
        <apex:actionStatus id="LargeStatus">
            <apex:facet name="start">
            <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ProgressIndicatorLarge)}" />
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:facet name="stop">
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>
    </div>
<apex:outputPanel id="out">    
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel id="mainOutputPanel">
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!doAllSearch}" name="showSearch"
    status="LargeStatus"
    reRender="resultBlock,pnlDisplayMsg,resultTable,error,footerPanel" />

    <apex:actionFunction name="mainSearch" action="{!doAllSearch}" status="searchStatus" reRender="resultBlock,error,filterBlock" />

    <apex:actionFunction action="{!relatedContactSearch}" name="searchContactResponse"
    rerender="contact" status="LargeStatus">
    <apex:param value="" assignTo="{!relatedEcid}" name="ecid"/>
    </apex:actionFunction>
    <apex:actionFunction name="nextAccountPage" action="{!nextPage}" oncomplete="document.getElementById('pg').scrollIntoView();"
    reRender="resultBlock,pnlDisplayMsg,resultTable,error,footerPanel" status="LargeStatus" />
    <apex:actionFunction name="previousAccountPage"
    action="{!previousPage}" oncomplete="document.getElementById('pg').scrollIntoView();"
    reRender="resultBlock,pnlDisplayMsg,resultTable" status="LargeStatus" />
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!sortData}" name="sortAccountData"
    reRender="resultBlock,pnlDisplayMsg,resultTable" status="LargeStatus">
    <apex:param name="sortField" assignTo="{!sortField}" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>

    <apex:actionFunction action="{!relatedContactSearch}" name="searchMarket"
    rerender="MarketAccount" status="LargeStatus">
    <apex:param value="" assignTo="{!relatedEcid}" name="ecid"/>
    </apex:actionFunction> 

    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!isPageBlock}" id="pbId"> <!-- --- Search Page block starts here ----->    

    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">  <!-- --- Search Page block section starts here ----->    

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:inputtext id="searchString" value="{!searchString}" 
        style="width:70%" />
        <script>


        </script>
        <apex:outputLabel value="Search Type: " />
        <apex:selectList value="{!searchOperator}" size="1" style="height: 22px;">
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="AND" itemvalue="AND"></apex:selectOption>
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="OR" itemvalue="OR"></apex:selectOption>
        </apex:selectList> &nbsp;&nbsp;

        <apex:actionStatus id="searchStatus">
        <apex:facet name="start">
        <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ProgressIndicator)}" />
        </apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="stop">
        <apex:commandButton value="Search" onclick="mainSearch();return false;" />
        </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
    <apex:outputPanel id="filterBlock">

    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!isLoadPage}" id="pbIdBlk">
    <div style="width:35%;" id="maindiv">
    <apex:pageblocksection >
    <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputlabel value="Account Filters" style="font-weight:bold"/>
    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>


    <apex:pageblockSectionItem >

    <a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv()" id="showlink" style="display:none;" >HideFilter</a> 
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv()" id="hidelink" >ShowFilter</a>
    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

    </apex:pageblocksection> 
    </div>

        <apex:outputPanel id="showblock" style="display:none;">
           <apex:pageblockSection columns="3" id="pbsi">
            <apex:repeat value="{!filterArray}" var="a">
              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!a.label}"/>
                  <apex:inputText value="{!a.SearchValue}" id="searchTextId"/>
              </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
              </apex:repeat> 
              <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:commandLink value="Clear Filters" onclick = "clearFilter()"/>
              </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="hideblock" style="display:none;">

        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection> <!-- --- Search Page Section block End here ----->    



    <apex:pageMessages id="error"/>
    <apex:pageBlock id="resultBlock"> <!-- --- Result Page block starts here ----->    
        <!-- Custom Header, apex facet doen't support text and ActionStatus -->
        <div class="pbHeader" style="margin: -0px -12px !important;">

        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="report">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td class="pbTitle">
        <h2 class="mainTitle"><!-- <nobr>SFDC Data {!IF((searchCount==0 || searchCount>=limitRecords), '', ' [' + TEXT(searchCount) + ']')}</nobr> -->
        Search Results</h2>

        </td>
        <td class="pbButton"><apex:actionStatus id="accountStatus">
        <apex:facet name="start">
        <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ProgressIndicator)}" />
        </apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="stop">
        <apex:commandButton value="New Account" action="{!newSObject}" 
        disabled="{!IF(showNewButton = true, false, true)}" status="accountStatus"
        rendered="{!newAccountAccess}"/>
        </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus></td>
        <td><apex:actionStatus id="statusSFDC">
        <apex:facet name="start">

        <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ProgressIndicator)}" />
        </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <apex:outputPanel id="resultTable">
        <table width="100%" class="list" border="0" cellspacing="0"
        cellpadding="0">
        <tr class="headerRow">
        <th style="width: 5%;">Action</th>
        <th style="width: 2%;"></th>
        <th style="width: 5%;"><apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputLink value="javascript:void(0);" disabled="{!IF(searchCount > 0, false, true)}"
        onclick="sortAccountDataJS('score');">Relevance<img
        src="{!IF(sortField = 'score',IF(isAsc = true,'/img/sort_asc_arrow.gif','/img/sort_desc_arrow.gif'),'/s.gif')}" />
        </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:outputPanel></th>
        <th style="width: 25%;"><apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputLink value="javascript:void(0);" disabled="{!IF(searchCount > 0, false, true)}"
        onclick="sortAccountDataJS('FULL_NAME_AC');">Account Name<img
        src="{!IF(sortField = 'FULL_NAME_AC',IF(isAsc = true,'/img/sort_asc_arrow.gif','/img/sort_desc_arrow.gif'),'/s.gif')}" />

        </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:outputPanel> <apex:actionStatus id="sortName">
        <apex:facet name="start">
        <span style="color: red;">Loading</span>
        <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ProgressIndicator)}" />
        </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus></th>
        <th style="width: 14%;"><apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputLink value="javascript:void(0);" disabled="{!IF(searchCount > 0, false, true)}"
        onclick="sortAccountDataJS('PRIM_ADDR_LN_1');">Street Address <img
        src="{!IF(sortField = 'PRIM_ADDR_LN_1',IF(isAsc = true,'/img/sort_asc_arrow.gif','/img/sort_desc_arrow.gif'),'/s.gif')}" />
        </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:outputPanel></th>
        <th style="width: 14%;"><apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputLink value="javascript:void(0);" disabled="{!IF(searchCount > 0, false, true)}"
        onclick="sortAccountDataJS('PRIM_CITY');">City <img
        src="{!IF(sortField = 'PRIM_CITY',IF(isAsc = true,'/img/sort_asc_arrow.gif','/img/sort_desc_arrow.gif'),'/s.gif')}" />
        </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:outputPanel></th>
        <th style="width: 14%;"><apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputLink value="javascript:void(0);" disabled="{!IF(searchCount > 0, false, true)}"
        onclick="sortAccountDataJS('PRIM_STATE');"> State/Province <img
        src="{!IF(sortField = 'PRIM_STATE',IF(isAsc = true,'/img/sort_asc_arrow.gif','/img/sort_desc_arrow.gif'),'/s.gif')}" />
        </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:outputPanel></th>
        <th style="width: 14%;"><apex:outputPanel >

        <apex:outputLink value="javascript:void(0);" disabled="{!IF(searchCount > 0, false, true)}"
        onclick="sortAccountDataJS('PRIM_POSTAL_CD');"> Zip/Postal Code <img
        src="{!IF(sortField = 'PRIM_POSTAL_CD',IF(isAsc = true,'/img/sort_asc_arrow.gif','/img/sort_desc_arrow.gif'),'/s.gif')}" />
        </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:outputPanel></th>
        <th style="width: 14%;"><apex:outputPanel >

        <apex:outputLink value="javascript:void(0);" disabled="{!IF(searchCount > 0, false, true)}"
        onclick="sortAccountDataJS('PRIM_COUNTRY_NM');"> Country <img
        src="{!IF(sortField = 'PRIM_COUNTRY_NM',IF(isAsc = true,'/img/sort_asc_arrow.gif','/img/sort_desc_arrow.gif'),'/s.gif')}" />
        </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:outputPanel></th>
        <!--
        <th style="width: 14%;"><apex:outputPanel >

        Immediate Parent
        </apex:outputPanel></th>
        <th style="width: 14%;"><apex:outputPanel >

        Ultimate Parent
        </apex:outputPanel></th>
        -->
        </tr>


        <apex:repeat value="{!searchResults}" var="searchResultObj">
        <tr>
        <td><apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(hyperlinkMap[searchResultObj.ecId].isAccountExist=false,true,false)}">
        <apex:commandLink action="{!createCDMSObject}" value="Create" rendered="{!newAccountAccess}">
        <apex:param name="firstParam"
        value="{!searchResultObj.ecId}" />
        </apex:commandLink>
        </apex:outputPanel></td>
        <td>
        <div id="option-{!searchResultObj.ecId}"
        onclick="popup('acc-{!searchResultObj.ecId}');"
        style="cursor: pointer;">+</div>

        </td>
        <td><apex:image value="/img/samples/color_green.gif" width="{!searchResultObj.scoreWidth}" height="15"/><apex:image value="/img/samples/color_yellow.gif" width="{!50-searchResultObj.scoreWidth}" height="15"/></td>
        <td><apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(hyperlinkMap[searchResultObj.ecId].isAccountExist=true,true,false)}">
        <a href="/{!hyperlinkMap[searchResultObj.ecId].relatedSObject['id']}">{!searchResultObj.fullOrgName}</a>
        </apex:outputText> <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(hyperlinkMap[searchResultObj.ecId].isAccountExist=false,true,false)}">{!searchResultObj.fullOrgName} </apex:outputText>
        </td>
        <td><apex:outputText value="{!searchResultObj.primaryAddr1}" />
        <br></br><apex:outputText value="{!searchResultObj.primaryAddr2}" />
        <br></br><apex:outputText value="{!searchResultObj.primaryAddr3}" />
        </td>
        <td><apex:outputText value="{!searchResultObj.primaryCity}" /></td>
        <td><apex:outputText value="{!searchResultObj.primaryState}" /></td>
        <td><apex:outputText value="{!searchResultObj.primaryZip}" /></td>
        <td><apex:outputText value="{!searchResultObj.primaryCountry}" /></td>
        <!--
        <td>
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!searchResultObj.ipsrc == 'SFDC'}">
        <a target="_blank" href="/{!searchResultObj.ipid}"><span style="color:red">{!searchResultObj.ipname}</span></a>
        </apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!searchResultObj.ipsrc == 'CDM'}">
        <span style="color:black">{!searchResultObj.ipname}</span>
        </apex:outputText>
        </td>
        <td>
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!searchResultObj.upsrc == 'SFDC'}">
        <a target="_blank" href="/{!searchResultObj.upid}"><span style="color:red">{!searchResultObj.upname}</span></a>
        </apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!searchResultObj.upsrc == 'CDM'}">
        <span style="color:black">{!searchResultObj.upname}</span>
        </apex:outputText>
        </td>
        -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="border: 0px;padding:0px"></td>
        <td colspan="8" style="border: 0px;padding:0px">
        <div id="panel-{!searchResultObj.ecId}"
        style="display: none" class="">
        <div class="container">
        <ul class="tabs">
        <li id="tab1-{!searchResultObj.ecId}" class="tab-link current"
        data-tab="tab-1{!searchResultObj.ecId}"
        onClick="showTab('tab1-{!searchResultObj.ecId}');"
        style="width: 20%;"><b>Account Details</b></li>
        <li id="tab2-{!searchResultObj.ecId}" class="tab-link"
        data-tab="tab-2{!searchResultObj.ecId}"
        onClick="showTab('tab2-{!searchResultObj.ecId}'),searchContactResponse('{!searchResultObj.ecId}');"
        style="width: 20%;"><b>Contacts</b></li>

        <li id="tab3-{!searchResultObj.ecId}" class="tab-link"
        data-tab="tab-3{!searchResultObj.ecId}"
        onClick="showTab('tab3-{!searchResultObj.ecId}'),searchMarket('{!searchResultObj.ecId}');"
        style="width: 20%;"><b>Source Systems</b></li>

        </ul>
        <div id="tab-1{!searchResultObj.ecId}"
        class="tab-content current" style="height: 100px;overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div class="tabl">
        <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='form_table'
        class='table01'>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Account Name </b></td>
        <td>{!searchResultObj.fullOrgName}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><b> Primary Address </b></td>
        <td>{!searchResultObj.primaryAddr1} <br />
        {!searchResultObj.primaryAddr3}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><b> City </b></td>
        <td>{!searchResultObj.primaryCity}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><b> Phone</b></td>
        <td>{!searchResultObj.primaryPhoneNumber}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><b> ECID</b></td>
        <td>{!searchResultObj.ecid}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="tab-3{!searchResultObj.ecId}" class="tab-content " style="height: 120px;overflow-y: scroll;">

        <!-- XREF Starts Here -->
        <apex:outputPanel id="MarketAccount">
        <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='form_table'
        class='table01'>

        <tr>
        <th> Source System</th>
        <th> Source Id</th>
        <th> Market Outlet Code</th>
        </tr>
        <apex:repeat value="{!marketOuterMap[searchResultObj.ecId]}" var="marketOutletObj">
        <apex:repeat value="{!marketOutletObj}" var="key">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <apex:outputText >
        {!marketOuterMap[searchResultObj.ecId][marketOutletObj].sourceSystem}
        </apex:outputText> 
        </td>

        <td>{!marketOuterMap[searchResultObj.ecId][marketOutletObj].sourceSystemId} </td>

        <td>{!marketOuterMap[searchResultObj.ecId][marketOutletObj].marketOutletCode}</td> 
        </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
        </apex:repeat>  
        </table>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <!-- XREF Ends Here-->

        </div>

        <div id="tab-2{!searchResultObj.ecId}" class="tab-content " style="height: 120px;overflow-y: scroll;">
        <apex:outputPanel id="contact">
        <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='form_table'>
        <tr>
        <th><b> First Name  </b></th>
        <th><b> Last Name  </b></th>
        <th><b> ECID  </b></th>
        <th><b> Email  </b></th>
        <th><b> City  </b></th>
        </tr>
        <apex:repeat value="{!relatedSobject[searchResultObj.ecId]}" var="searchResultObj"> 

        <tr>
        <td>{!searchResultObj.firstName}</td>

        <td>{!searchResultObj.lastName}</td>

        <td>{!searchResultObj.ecId}</td>

        <td>{!searchResultObj.email}</td>

        <td>{!searchResultObj.primaryCity}</td>
        </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
        </table>
        </apex:outputPanel></div>
        <!--
        <script>alert('{!searchResultObj.ecId}');</script>
        <div id="tab-3{!searchResultObj.ecId}" class="tab-content ">
        Transaction Details
        </div>
        -->
        </div>

        </div>

        </td>
        </tr>
        </apex:repeat>

        </table>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputPanel id="footerPanel" rendered="{!NOT(searchCount==0)}">
        <hr />
        <table width="100%" border="0px" cellspacing="0px"
        cellpadding="0px">
        <tr>
        <td align="left" width="33%">
        <div id="pagelinkblock"><nobr> Show &nbsp; <apex:selectList value="{!maxRow}" size="1"
        onchange="document.getElementById('pg').scrollIntoView();showSearch();">
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="10" itemvalue="10"></apex:selectOption>
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="25" itemvalue="25"></apex:selectOption>
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="50" itemvalue="50"></apex:selectOption>
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="100" itemvalue="100"></apex:selectOption>
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="200" itemvalue="200"></apex:selectOption>
        </apex:selectList>
        <div id="curstate"><nobr>Records per page:
        {!showingFrom} - {!showingTo} of &nbsp;
        <apex:outputText value="{0, number,###,###,##0}">
        <apex:param value="{!totalRecords}"/>
        </apex:outputText>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></div>
        </nobr></div>
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="33%" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <nobr> <apex:outputLink value="javascript:void(0);"
        rendered="{!isPreviousPageAvailable}"
        onclick="previousAccountPage();">&lt;&lt;Previous
        </apex:outputLink> <span id="div_mid1">&nbsp; <apex:outputLabel value="|"
        rendered="{!isPreviousPageAvailable && isNextPageAvailable}" />&nbsp;
        </span> <apex:outputLink value="javascript:void(0);"
        rendered="{!isNextPageAvailable}" onclick="nextAccountPage();">Next&gt;&gt;</apex:outputLink>
        <apex:outputText >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   </apex:outputText>
        <!-- <apex:outputLink value="javascript:void(0);"
        rendered="{!AND(totalPage==currentPage)}"
        onclick="fetchMoreSSCE();">Fetch More&gt;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   
        </apex:outputLink> --> </nobr></td>
        <td align="right" width="33%" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <nobr>
        <div id="pagenumber"><nobr>Page &nbsp; <apex:inputText value="{!requestedPage}" style="width:40px" />of &nbsp;
        <apex:outputText value="{0, number,###,###,##0}">
        <apex:param value="{!totalPage}"/>
        </apex:outputText>

        <apex:actionStatus id="goStatus">
        <apex:facet name="start">
        <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ProgressIndicator)}" />
        </apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="stop">
        <apex:commandButton value="Go" action="{!requestedPage}" oncomplete="document.getElementById('pg').scrollIntoView();" reRender="resultBlock,pnlDisplayMsg,resultTable,error,footerPanel" status="goStatus" rendered="{!IF(searchCount <= maxRow,false,true)}"/>     
        </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>

        </nobr>
        </div>
        </nobr></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF((searchTerm== '' && searchTerm == null ),false,true)}">
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(searchResults.size = 0,true,false) }">No search results found for <b> {!searchTerm} </b></apex:outputText>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>   <!-- --- Result Page block End here ----->    

    </apex:pageBlock> <!-- --- Search Page block End here ----->    
    <apex:outputPanel id="createAccountPanel">
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb" title="Create Account" rendered="{!isShow}"> <!-- --- Create New Account Page block starts here ----->    
    <apex:pageMessages id="errormsg" />
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Account Details"
    collapsible="false">
    <apex:inputText style="width: 561px;"  value="{!editExtObj.currentSObject['Name']}"  />
    <!--Start Change Added for Case#1396391 -->                
    <apex:inputField style="width: 561px;"  value="{!editExtObj.currentSObject['Account_Acronym__c']}"/>
    <!--End Change -->                  
    <apex:inputField style="width: 561px;"  value="{!editExtObj.currentSObject['ParentId']}"/>
    <!--  <apex:inputText value="{!editExtObj.currentSObject['Phone']}" />-->
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedRecordType}" size="1" label="Record Type" style="width: 173px;" >
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!recordTypes}" />
    <apex:actionSupport action="{!fillTier1Classification}" oncomplete="setTierClassification();" status="LargeStatus" event="onchange" reRender="tier1classification,acctType,acctTypeLabel"/>
    </apex:selectList>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
    <apex:outputLabel >Tier 1 Classification</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="tier1classification">
    <apex:inputField styleClass="Tier_1_Classification"  value="{!tierAccount.Tier_1_Classification__c}" label="Tier 1 Classification" rendered="{!IF(selectedRecordType!='',true,false)}" />                        
    <apex:selectList label="Tier 1 Classification" size="1" multiselect="false" rendered="{!IF(selectedRecordType='',true,false)}">
    </apex:selectList>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!isCDMSObject}"
    value="{!editExtObj.currentSObject['ECID__c']}" />
    <c:PhoneValidation PhoneWrap="{!accountPhone}" />

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
    <apex:outputPanel id="acctTypeLabel">
    <apex:outputLabel rendered="{!selectedRecordType=='012d0000000xGxuAAE'}">Type</apex:outputLabel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="acctType">
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedType}" size="1" style="width: 173px;" rendered="{!selectedRecordType=='012d0000000xGxuAAE'}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!AccountTypes}" />
    </apex:selectList>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>



    <apex:inputField style="width: 561px;"  value="{!editExtObj.currentSObject['Website']}"/>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <c:GoogleAddressValidation />
    <apex:actionRegion >
    <c:PrimaryAddress id="pcom"
    PriForceValidation="{!editExtObj.isPrimaryForceValidation}" addressWrapper="{!editExtObj.primaryAddressWrapper}" />
    </apex:actionRegion>
    <c:AdditionalAddresses id="acom"
    AddiForceValidation="{!editExtObj.isAdditionalForceValidation}" addressWrapper="{!editExtObj.additionalAddressObj}" />
    <apex:actionStatus id="AccountStatus">
    <apex:facet name="start">

    <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ProgressIndicator)}" />
    </apex:facet>
    <apex:facet name="stop">
    <apex:actionRegion >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!previousSearchResult}" oncomplete="document.getElementById('pg').scrollIntoView();"  style="margin-left: 15px;" status="AccountStatus" value="Search Result" reRender="mainOutputPanel"/>
    </apex:actionRegion>
    </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionStatus>

    <apex:actionStatus id="SaveStatus">
    <apex:facet name="start">
    <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ProgressIndicator)}" />
    </apex:facet>
    <apex:facet name="stop">
    <apex:actionRegion >
    <input type="button" style="width: 5%;" class="btn" value="Save" onclick="Save();"/>
    </apex:actionRegion>
    </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionStatus>


    <apex:actionFunction name="Save" action="{!dosave}" reRender="frm,errorPanel" oncomplete="document.getElementById('pg').scrollIntoView();" status="SaveStatus"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>  <!-- --- Create New Account Page block End here ----->    
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>   
<!-- mainOutputPanel -->
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Thanks for these ~550 lines of code...but surely not all of them are relevant?

Comment: Why i pasted everything is , inputtext is inside many panels and page blocks thats y.  I need to set null to this elelmnt, <apex:inputText value="{!a.SearchValue}" id="searchTextId"/>

Comment: If you can't isolate the problem to a few dozen lines of code at most, what makes you think strangers on the internet are going to do it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generally accomplish this with a css selector.  You can either search for all elements with ids containing your textboxes' ID, or add a class to the textboxes to search for:

```
textarea[id*='searchTextId']

.searchTextClass
```

Then just use `document.querySelectorAll` to get a collection of all the text boxes and clear them:

```
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('textarea[id*="searchTextId"]');
for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; ++i)
{
    boxes[i].value = '';
}
```